# Javascript: Play Sound in Browser: Persist somehow that a user interacted with this page?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, audio

current browsers disallow JS to play a sound unless the user interacted with the page first. See
https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes

I do have a page which visualizes the CO2 value of a sensor, and if the value is too high, it should play an alarm sound using JS. For doin so, there is a button which toggles sound on/off.

When the user interacts with the page, JS is allowed to play the sound.
**But when exactly the same URL is reloaded (on the very same machine), the user has to interact again with the page to allow JS to play the sound.** I would somehow like to be able to persist the state that the user interacted with this particular URL already, so I can play the warning sound when the same URL is reloaded and the user selected before that the sound should play. Is there a way to do this?

To give you a better impression, here are 2 Screenshots with warning sound turned on/off by the user. I would like to persist this selection (no problem using localStorage), but Chrome disallows playing the sound after reloadinf the page unless the user interacts again. I would like to be allowed to play that sound after a page reload.

[image: Sound turned on by user]

[image: Sound turned off by user]

Thanks & bests regards
Philipp

Comment: There is no way to do it.

Comment: there was a change pushed to all browsers about 3 years ago to disable media including audio unless browser encountered user interaction ... you can force the hand on this ... it would help if you posted  minumum code which shows how your audio gets rendered

Comment: Perhaps it could be an idea to look into the [Notifcation API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification). If I am not mistaken, once you have given the web page permission to give you notifications the browser will remember this setting. Note this is an alternative to making the page itself play a sound.

Comment: [Firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/block-autoplay) and [Brave](https://support.brave.com/hc/en-us/articles/360018205431-How-do-I-change-site-permissions-) have site permissions, which include autoplay (you could ask your users to allow it), [Chrome doesn't](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes). And my best idea would be to force the interaction: Have a 50 % transparent overlay which says something like "Klicke, um den Alarm zu aktivieren"